# GTest parameter function failed to compile: where to fix?

Tags: c++, parameters, compilation, googletest

My code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
bool IsEven(int i){return i%2==0;}
class IsEvenParamTest:public testing::TestWithParam<int>{};
INITIALIZE_TEST_CASE_P(MySuccess,IsEvenParamTest,testing::Range(2,6));
TEST_P(IsEvenParamTest, All){
    int n = GetParam();
    EXPECT_TRUE(IsEven(n));
}
```

g++ compiles and failed:

```
mytest.cpp:4:23: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
INITIALIZE_TEST_CASE_P(MySuccess,IsEvenParamTest,testing::Range(2,6));
                   ^
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Should it not be `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P`?

Comment: Corrected!............

Comment: any update on this question? 
Since I'm facing the same problem atm.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a possible solution: as explained on [Googletest's bug tracker](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2065#issuecomment-473861429-permalink)  the name of the macro has been changed after 1.8.0:

> `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P` works for master, `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` works for 1.8.0

So if you are following old documents but using a newer version of GTest (or the other way around, like me) you should use the other macro.